# Turn DirectoryStream into lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Can this code be turned into lambda expression? I tried a lot but I didn't get it.

```
DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> dirFilter = new DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path dir) throws IOException {
        return Files.isDirectory(dir);
    }
};
Path baseDirectory = getProjectDir();
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(baseDirectory, dirFilter)) {
    for(Path path : dirStream) {
        System.out.println(path.getFileName());
    }
} catch(IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `Files.newDirectoryStream(baseDir, Files::isDirectory).forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Thanks alot!! Solved by: Files.newDirectoryStream(baseDirectory,
                Files::isDirectory).forEach(path -> {
                    System.out.println(path.getFileName());
                });

Answer (score 7):

This can be simply written as:

```
DirectoryStream.Filter<Path> dirFilter = Files::isDirectory;
Path baseDirectory = getProjectDir();
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(baseDirectory, dirFilter)) {
    dirStream.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getFileName()));
}
```

First, the creation of the anonymous class for `DirectoryStream.Filter` is replaced with the [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `Files::isDirectory`. This works because:

- The method reference `Files::isDirectory` is exactly the same as the [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) `path -> Files.isDirectory(path)`.
- This lambda expression has a single formal parameter `Path` and returns a `boolean`.
- Such a signature conforms with the signature of the only method [`boolean accept(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.Filter.html#accept-T-) of the [`DirectoryStream.Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/DirectoryStream.Filter.html) interface.

Then, the rest of the code uses the new method [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) that was added to [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) (which `DirectoryStream` is). This method takes a single parameter that is a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html), which can be expressed as a lambda expression taking a single parameter of type `Path` and returning no result (the argument for this is the same as above).